# Getting error NMinimize::nnum: in quantum physics code

Tags: numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization, warning-messages

The following code generate the error:

> NMinimize::nnum: The function value Ω[42/125, 0,1.91862121487240651285721, 1.71668875337901960520526] is not a number at {Δ, Σ} = {1.91862121487240651285721, 1.71668875337901960520526}.

Basically, what my code does is find the eigenfunction of some physical variable (a matrix). So `eig` is the group of eigenroots. There are 48 roots. One of the 48 roots has the implicit format as `Root[ #1&, 8]`. Means the 8th root of a expression. Other 47 roots are nice and explicit.

Then, an `Ep` function is defined as the summation of some absolute values of these eigen values. `Ep` has 24 elements. Without inserting any number, it has a lot roots in the implicit format because of the `Abs` function. But mathematically, it should have the good behavior.

Then another function, `Ω`, is created based on `Ep`. It is an integration of `Ω` together with something else. And with some of the parameters (`Λ`, etc.) known, `Ω` has only one element.

`Ω` has four arguments and now I am search for the values of the last two variables which make the `Ω` smallest for given series of the first two variables. For this I used `NMinimize`.

I have used `?NumericQ` for the `NIntegrate` part in `Ω` so the `Ω` part will be evaluated only when Mathematica evaluates different specific values for the variables.

However, the error shows up. From the physical point of view, `Ω` should be well defined and should not have a gap at any point.

Any possible reason of having this error? Please ignore the code before `eig`, for people who is not very familar with quantum physics, it looks a little bit confusing, but it is quiet simple and should cause this error.

The Code:

```
tN = ({{0, 0}, {0, 0}}); 
t0 = ({{1, 0}, {0, 1}}); 
t1 = ({{0, 1}, {1, 0}}); 
t2 = ({{0, -I}, {I, 0}}); 
t3 = ({{1, 0}, {0, -1}});

la2 = ( {{0, -I, 0}, {I, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}} ); 
la5 = ( {{0, 0, -I}, {0, 0, 0}, {I, 0, 0}} ); 
la7 = ( {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -I}, {0, I, 0}} ); 
la0 = ( {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}} );

gaN = KroneckerProduct[tN, tN];
gaI = KroneckerProduct[t0, t0];
ga0 = ArrayFlatten[{{tN, t0}, {t0, tN}}];
ga1 = ArrayFlatten[{{tN, t1}, {-t1, tN}}];
ga2 = ArrayFlatten[{{tN, t2}, {-t2, tN}}];
ga3 = ArrayFlatten[{{tN, t3}, {-t3, tN}}];
ga5 = I*ga0.ga1.ga2.ga3;

ga0t0 = KroneckerProduct[t0, ga0];
ga1t0 = KroneckerProduct[t0, ga1];
ga2t0 = KroneckerProduct[t0, ga2];
ga3t0 = KroneckerProduct[t0, ga3];

gaIt0 = KroneckerProduct[t0, gaI];

ga5t1 = KroneckerProduct[t1, ga5];
ga5t2 = KroneckerProduct[t2, ga5];
ga5t3 = KroneckerProduct[t3, ga5];

ga0t3 = KroneckerProduct[t3, ga0];
ga05t3 = KroneckerProduct[t3, ga0.ga5];

Matpu = p0*ga0t0 - 0*ga1t0 - 0*ga2t0 - p*ga3t0 - \[Sigma]*gaIt0 - 
   I*0*ga5t3 - \[Mu]*ga0t0 + \[Nu]5*ga05t3;
Matpula = KroneckerProduct[la0, Matpu];
Matpd = p0*ga0t0 - 0*ga1t0 - 0*ga2t0 - p*ga3t0 - \[Sigma]*gaIt0 - 
   I*0*ga5t3 + \[Mu]*ga0t0 + \[Nu]5*ga05t3;
Matpdla = KroneckerProduct[la0, Matpd];

ga1t1 = KroneckerProduct[t1, ga1];
ga2t1 = KroneckerProduct[t1, ga2];
ga3t1 = KroneckerProduct[t1, ga3];

Matde = (KroneckerProduct[la2, ga3t1] + KroneckerProduct[la5, ga2t1] +
     KroneckerProduct[la7, ga1t1]);
MatdeC = ConjugateTranspose[Matde];
Mat = ArrayFlatten[{{Matpula, \[CapitalDelta]*
      Matde}, {-\[CapitalDelta]*MatdeC, Matpdla}}];
eig = p0 /. Solve[Det[Mat] == 0, p0]

\[CapitalLambda] = 6134/10000;
G = 225/(100*\[CapitalLambda]^2);
H = G*3/8;
m = 542/100000;

fun[p_, \[Mu]_, \[Nu]5_, \[CapitalDelta]_, \[Sigma]_] = eig;
len = Length[eig];
Ep[p_, \[Mu]_, \[Nu]5_, \[CapitalDelta]_, \[Sigma]_] = 
  Sum[Abs[fun[p, \[Mu], \[Nu]5, \[CapitalDelta], \[Sigma]][[i]]], {i, 
    1, len}];

\[CapitalOmega][\[Mu]_?NumericQ, \[Nu]5_?NumericQ, \
\[CapitalDelta]_?NumericQ, \[Sigma]_?NumericQ] := (\[Sigma] - m)^2/(
   2*G) + (3*\[CapitalDelta]^2)/(2*H) - 
   1/(2*(2*\[Pi]^2))*
    NIntegrate[
     p^2*Ep[p, \[Mu], \[Nu]5, \[CapitalDelta], \[Sigma]]*\
\[CapitalLambda]^(2*5)/(\[CapitalLambda]^(2*5) + p^(2*5)), {p, 0, 
      10*\[CapitalLambda]}, PrecisionGoal -> 12, AccuracyGoal -> 12, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 24];


FuncMin[\[Mu]_, \[Nu]5_] := 
  NMinimize[{\[CapitalOmega][\[Mu], \[Nu]5, \[CapitalDelta], \
\[Sigma]], \[CapitalDelta] >= 0 && \[Sigma] > 
      0}, {\[CapitalDelta], \[Sigma]}, PrecisionGoal -> 12, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 12, WorkingPrecision -> 24];
time = TimeUsed[]

Clear[ls];
ls = {};
Do[AppendTo[ls, 
  ParallelTable[
   FuncMin[\[Mu], (i - 1)*6/1000], {\[Mu], 3/10, 51/100, 
    3/1000}]], {i, 1, 60}]
```

Comment: You should use a question mark for `?NumericQ`.  You have some strange unicode character in your posted code that looks like a question mark.  Changing that I don't get the `NMinimize` error.  (Also, does one really need to do 60 parallel calls to show the problem?)

Comment: Yes. Michael. I had a wrong question mark.I have fixed it. So far it didn't show anything wrong. No, 60 is not absolutely necessary. With the question mark, it shows an error at every point.  Will let it run for a while to make sure it is all due to the wrong question mark.

Comment: Based on this ?NumericQ Method. Does it make a difference if I change the NIntegrate to Integrate? Because there is no numerical evaluation of the omiga out side of the NMinimize, right?

Comment: `Integrate` will try to evaluate the integral symbolically (and exactly).  This usually takes longer.  I would use `NIntegrate`. Unless you need 12 digits of precision, I would lower `PrecisionGoal` to what is acceptable to you or slightly higher. (But maybe you want 12.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ASCII question marks in `?NumericQ`, the warnings change to `NIntegrate::precw` working precision warnings. `NMinimize` works with 24-digit precision and passes 24-digit parameters to `Ω`, which calls `NIntegrate`. The precision warnings arise because rounding error causes the integrand to lose some precision, so that in `NIntegrate`, the integrand has less than 24 digits of precision. One way to get rid of the warnings is to use `Quiet`:

```
Ω[μ_?NumericQ, ν5_?NumericQ, Δ_?NumericQ, σ_?NumericQ] :=
  Quiet[
   (σ - m)^2/(2*G) + (3*Δ^2)/(2*H) - 
    1/(2*(2*π^2)) *
     NIntegrate[
      p^2*Ep[p, μ, ν5, Δ, σ] * Λ^(2*5)/(Λ^(2*5) + p^(2*5)),
      {p, 0, 10*Λ}, PrecisionGoal -> 12, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 12, WorkingPrecision -> 24],
   {NIntegrate::precw}
   ];
```

Another is to increase WP a few digits in `NMinimize` to something like `WorkingPrecision -> 27`. `NMinimize` does not complain when less than 27 digits are returned from the objective function `Ω`.  I suppose it expects some rounding-related loss of precision.

Thirdly, you can override the loss of `Precision` with [`$MinPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$MinPrecision.html).  It does not actually lessen the rounding error.  It just artificially keeps the [`Precision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Precision.html) from going below a certain number.

```
FuncMin[μ_, ν5_] := Block[{$MinPrecision = 24},
   NMinimize[{Ω[μ, ν5, Δ, σ], Δ >= 0 && σ > 0}, {Δ, σ}, PrecisionGoal -> 12, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 12, WorkingPrecision -> 24]
   ];
```

Finally, you can simply ignore the warnings.  The first and third approaches above effectively are doing that anyway.  They just prevent the annoying red messages.  They do allow other error/warning messages to be printed, which is of value in general.

*Remark: A single call to `FuncMin` seems to take at least a few minutes.  A warning would be nice.  I have not let even one call finish.*

Comment: Thanks for the in depth review of the code and the suggestion. I am running the NIntegrrate version now. Yes the 12 digit accuracy and precisionGoal are preferred. The reason to use the Integrate was because I thought In the final FuncMin, the only place where numerical calculation is done, using Integrate lets the system merge Omiga and FuncMin and may simplify it internally (I guess) before doing numerial evaluation. If NIntegrate is used, however, the system might calculate the  numerial integration first and then calculate the remaining part of the FuncMin. Obviously I am wrong.

Comment: Yes. It is quiet slow, each point of this code currently takes a hour for a decent i7 cpu core on version 11.2. I am trying my best to speed it up. I think the reason is that one term of the integrand is an implicit expression of a root. So within the integration, it first numerically solve the polynomial formula to find the root and then calculate the integration. I think next I will try choosing the algorithm of the NMinimize manually to test. For the precision passing part, shouldn't I put higher WP in the NIntegrate since it is calculated first and then lower WP in the NMinimize?

Comment: If you can get `Integrate` to calculate the integral symbolically once and use the result, then that would be better.  But it ran for a few minutes before I killed it.  As for which WP should be higher, you can try it both ways, but I think I'm right.  (Try it on a single `FuncMin` call.)  `FindMinimum` is faster than `NMinimize` in cases where there are not multiple local minima.  I don't know if that's the case here.